# Continuous layout with DIVs

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="top">
*height: auto;
min-height: 100%;*

    <div id="content">
    *min-height: 500px;*
    </div>

    <div id="middle">
    *css ???*
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">    
</div>
```

This code works nice when the screen size is normal. But in full screen mode, the footer goes to the bottom of the page (wanted behaviour) but the ''middle'' div must increase its height to get the footer. I mean, the 3 elements (content, middle and footer) must be continuous.

Which css rules should I use to do this behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE.

I've used a couple css rules and works, but don't in IE8 (works in IE9, Chrome, FF3 e FF4). The relevant CSS is:

```
Top{ height: auto; }
Content{ min-height: 100%; }
Middle{ overflow: auto; padding-bottom: 130px; }
Footer{ clear: both; height: 130px; margin-top: -130px; position: relative; }
```

Comment: Do you want the footer to stay on the bottom of the screen always, or should it scroll when content pushes it down?

Comment: @Thomas Always on the bottom, but not fixed.

Comment: ah, okay. Check out my answer about media queries then. You can set widths and heights and any other css attribute based on the viewport height.

Answer (score 0):

`height:100%;` should be all that is needed to make it take up the available space.

Answer (score 0):

You might try CSS Media Queries with max or min-height. Examples here: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/CSS3MediaQueries/Default.html 
and documentation here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: Due to requisites, I must avoid CSS3

Comment: That stinks. I know people hate tables, but technically they woudl work in this situation - cell for top, middle, and bottom.  In that case the middle cell will always stretch down to meet the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

**The Bad News:** To be honest, mate, I don't think this is possible with this exact specification.  It would take some very clever css at any rate.  However, tables would work nicely.  I'm completely against the idea, but if this design requirement is a must, then perhaps you should go the route.

**The Good News:** Depending on *why* it is you need them to be fluid, we could maybe give the desired effect.  If it's just for backgrounds to match up, we could probably do that.  Update your post with more information and I'll (hopefully) update mine with an answer.

Comment: Hi The footer must be sticky on the bottom (but not fixed), the content div has a variable height and if the content div is too short, the middle div must grow to touch the footer to avoid a blank space between divs. I've used a couple css rules and works, but don't in IE8 (works in IE9, Chrome, FF3 e FF4). Please see the question above with the css I've used. Thanks :)

Comment: What I need to know is WHY you need to to grow.  If you are aligning stuff in the middle one vertically, then the method I know of won't work without javascript.  If a background needs to stretch to fill the gap, then I can help there as long as the content doesn't change vertical alignment.  Does that make sense?